# Get out how much will my current stock serves per month and days as decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am working on a stock in and out module where I have a quantity in my ware house and I have a plan of consumption for it per month, I need to know how much will the quantity in the stock will stay per month and days as decimal using an SQL Server query, below is the example

[image]

For example the quantity 4531 is enough for 11 months 
1132+1492+979+413+13 since if I add 1055 to it, the total will be in negative 
but in reality the quantity is enough for 11 months and few days and here is my problem, I need a way to be able to calculate these few days and integrate them with the month.

I have done the whole code and the loops to get the months calculation automatically using the query but I need the help on calculating the months and the days from the next month.

Comment: I am sure this makes sense to you since you are close to this project. But I keep looking at this and the more I look at it the less sense it makes. No idea what your source data is or what you expect as output. Please see this. [mcve]. Also, pictures of data are nearly worthless. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I guess you don't need help after all?

Comment: The basic formula would be: [Stock remaining at the start of the month] / [consumption] * [number of days in a month] .  What other help do you need?

Comment: what is relation between consumption and netstock ? What is Input ? What is expected output in simple word ?